# NSImage is not displayed correctly (size)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have an NSWindow with a custom view. When I execute the following code, the image is not displayed correctly. It is too small. The size of the image is 380x122. WHat am I doing wrong?

```
NSImage *imageFromBundle = [NSImage imageNamed:@"about.bmp"];
NSImageView *imageView = [[NSImageView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0,0,380,122)];
[imageView setImage: imageFromBundle];
[_aboutCustomView addSubview:imageView];
[_aboutWindow center];
[_aboutWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront: nil];
[_aboutWindow display];
```

Comment: Run a search for 'NSImage resolution.'

Comment: are you saying that the DPI has to be something specific?

Comment: Turns out that I just had to set the size: [imageFromBundle setSize:size]; where 'size' is of the type NSSize

Comment: `[imageView setImageScaling: NSImageScaleProportionallyUpOrDown]` probably would have worked too.

Comment: @user1884325 You should put your solution into an answer and mark it accepted, to make it easier for future site visitors to find.